How do you destroy/free a FILE object without closing the underlying file descriptor?
Say I have a file descriptor fd I got from pipe() which I want to read line-by-line.
I call FILE* f = fdopen(fd, "r") on it. Now I have a FILE* object.
What if I want to stop reading the fd line-by-line but still use the fd itself for something else? If I call fclose(f) it will also close the filedescriptor itself.
Is there any way to free a FILE object without closing the descriptor?
Edit, less theoretical example: I want to implement my own buffering logic for tmpfile, but that API only allows getting a FILE*. If I do want to have my own buffering I need to track the FILE* object to free it instead of the fileno. And no, mktemp() does't work as it has different behavior. I kind of doubt dup() will work in this case... though I'm going to try.

I just tried -- amazingly, dup works for tmpfile!


What is it you're trying to do?  It doesn't make sense that you're worried about a tiny bit of memory while you still want access to the file.  You can use the lower level open to eliminate the FILE but if you're on a system with 5 k of available memory already it may not save you much.

"How do you destroy/free a FILE object?" You don't, because the C standard doesn't say that fopen/fdopen create/allocate a FILE object. It's perfectly valid for a C implementation to have a static array of FILE structures that it simply reuses.

dup the file descriptor and fclose the file. You can then dup2 the new fd to the old fd, but this is up to you. Note that any buffer you might have still in your FILE will be lost.

@user3386109 okay, I just want to know how to disassociate it rather than "free" it then, same idea. If the API allows you to create a FILE object without opening it, IMO it should allow you to destroy one without closing. The answers seem to indicate this simply isn't supported (except through dup+dup2 schenanigans), thanks everyone.

@n.m.couldbeanAI You can then dup2 the new fd to the old fd, but this is up to you.  Be careful doing that in a multithreaded process.  I don't think there's a guaranteed thread-safe way to use dup2() to duplicate the value of an already-closed file descriptor.


Is there any way to free a FILE object without closing the descriptor?

Not portably — associating the file descriptor with a stream means that the stream is responsible for the underlying file, and thus, as you know, fclose() will close it.
Your best bet is to dup() the fd .  fopen() either the original or the duplicate, then use the other after the fclose().  Please bear in mind, as another answer highlights, that mixing buffered streams and "raw" descriptors can be dangerous.

As explained in my answer, this doesn't work since it results in data loss. (Copy)

@ikegami yes, that's an important observation, that mixing stream and descriptor I/O is dangerous.  It's not clear to me that the OP's intent is further I/O, however, as opposed to academic curiosity or, say, using the read-end of the pipe as an inherited, simple synchronization mechanism for child processes.

yes, my intent is more akin to curiosity rather than "I plan to do this thing for my production server" -- thanks everyone!

Actually, my real reason was because I didn't think you can use FILE objects for async IO and wanted to be able to go back and forth... can you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78337562/unix-get-specific-error-of-fdread-fgetc-etc

@vitiral, that sounds like a separate question, and you'll definitely want to heed @igekami's warning.


What if I want to stop reading the fd line-by-line

Use fread, fgetc, etc.
Reading from the fd (or a dup of it) could result in data loss as some of the data could be in the FILE's buffer.

Demo of data loss from reverting to using file descriptor:
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void ) {
   int pipefds[2];
   if ( pipe( pipefds ) == -1 )
      err( 1, "pipe" );
   
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if ( pid == -1 )
      err( 1, "fork" );

   if ( pid == 0 ) {
      close( pipefds[ 0 ] );

      FILE *fh = fdopen( pipefds[ 1 ], "w" );
      if ( fh == NULL)
         err( 1, "fdopen" );

      for ( unsigned i = 1;  i <= 1000;  ++i ) {
         if ( fprintf( fh, "This is line %u\n", i ) < 0 )
            err( 1, "fprintf" );
      }

      if ( fclose( fh ) == EOF )
         err( 1, "fclose" );

      exit( 0 );
   }

   close( pipefds[ 1 ] );

   int newfd = dup( pipefds[ 0 ] );
   if ( newfd == -1 )
      err( 1, "dup" );

   {
      FILE *fh = fdopen( pipefds[ 0 ], "r" );
      if ( fh == NULL )
         err( 1, "fdopen" );

      char *line = NULL;
      size_t n = 0;
      for ( unsigned i = 5;  i--; ) {
         ssize_t bytes_read = getline( &line, &n, fh );
         if ( bytes_read == -1 )
            err( 1, "getline" );
         if ( bytes_read == 0 )
            errx( 1, "Unexpected EOF" );

         if ( line[ bytes_read-1 ] == '\n' )
            line[ bytes_read-1 ] = 0;

         printf( "<%s>\n", line );
      }

      if ( fclose( fh ) == EOF )
         err( 1, "fclose" );

      free( line );
   }

   printf( "Following should start with \"This is line 6\" if there's no data loss:\n" );

   {
      char buf[ 31 ];
      ssize_t bytes_read = read( newfd, buf, 30 );
      if ( bytes_read == -1 )
         err( 1, "read" );

      buf[ bytes_read ] = 0;
      printf( "[%s]\n", buf );
   }
}

Output:
<This is line 1>
<This is line 2>
<This is line 3>
<This is line 4>
<This is line 5>
Following should start with "This is line 6" if there's no data loss:
[is line 248
This is line 249
T]

Lines 6 to 247 were lost, as well as the start of line 248.

Yes I should have been more clear, I meant that I just wanted to use the plain file descriptor without the buffer/etc. Thanks!

I know. I'm saying data might have already been read in to the FILE's buffer, so if you start reading from the plain fd, you might "skip" over part of the file. So you shouldn't do that. You should use fread, fgetc, etc.  If it was a plain file (as opposed to a pipe), you could just seek to the correct position. But you said it was a pipe.

A very very good point, thanks!
