Unix get specific error of fread, fgetc, etc?
I would like to get the specific error (EAGAIN) after reading this pipe. How do I do so?
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  int rw[2]; assert(!pipe(rw));
  int r = rw[0], w = rw[1];
  fcntl(r, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
  printf("This will return EAGAIN\n");
  printf(" read -> %i\n", read(r, buf, 10));
  printf(" errno = %i \"%s\" (EAGAIN=%i)\n", errno, strerror(errno), EAGAIN);

  errno = 0;
  FILE* f = fdopen(r, "r");
  printf(" fgetc -> %i (EOF=%i) errno=%i\n", fgetc(f), EOF, errno);
  printf(" ferror -> %i\n", ferror(f));
}

Prints
This will return EAGAIN
 read -> -1
 errno = 11 "Resource temporarily unavailable" (EAGAIN=11)
This doesn't give me any info
 fgetc -> -1 (EOF=-1) errno=0
 ferror -> 1


That's the problem with the stdio wrappers.  It's a level of abstraction that hides some detailed error information.

Wow, that's surprising and rather annoying. So you can't even get a description of the problem, just that there was an error?

No, but if you're dealing with a pipe like this, why would you want the buffered services anyway?  Why not use read and write?

The order of evaluation of function arguments isn't specified by C. Even if errno is left in a useful state after fgetc() errors, printf() might be getting passed its value before fgetc() is called if the arguments are evaluated right to left.

that was it, thanks Shawn! I added an answer to summarize

It was programmer error, thanks @Shawn for helping in the comments.

The order of evaluation of function arguments isn't specified by C.  Even if errno is left in a useful state after fgetc() errors, printf() might be getting passed its value before fgetc() is called if the arguments are evaluated right to left.

I now realize that fread() and friends don't mention errno at all -- meaning (I guess?) that they also don't modify errno if an error occurs. Pretty interesting!
I've modified the second bit with
  printf("Errno has the answers!\n");
  FILE* f = fdopen(r, "r");
  errno = 0;
  printf(" errno has been set to %i\n", errno);
  printf(" fgetc -> %i (EOF=%i)\n", fgetc(f), EOF);
  printf(" errno=%i (pre ferror)\n", errno);
  printf(" ferror -> %i\n", ferror(f));
  printf(" errno=%i\n", errno);

Which prints
Errno has the answers!
 errno has been set to 0
 fgetc -> -1 (EOF=-1)
 errno=11 (pre ferror)
 ferror -> 1
 errno=11


Quoting the ISO C Standard: "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."
